# repainting an applet from a swingworker used to compute triangles and circum-circles

Tags: java, swing, graphics, computational-geometry, swingworker

I am trying to replicate the applet found [here](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/studerende/duff/Fortune/) as a part of an exercise. The applet is using Fortune's algorithm to generate both; a Voronoi diagram and Delaunay triangulation. I am just interested in generating the Delaunay Triangulation in a plane and thus, would be using the incremental algorithms i.e. adding 1 point at a time. I intend to show the triangles being generated at every stage when a sample point is added.

I am using a SwingWorker class to create an instance of the Triangulate class which contains the algorithm. I am calling the triangulate method inside a for loop which iterates through the set of sample points when the start button on the GUI is clicked.

Here's the code for that:

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                SwingWorker<List<Triangle>, Triangle> worker = new SwingWorker<List<Triangle>, Triangle>() {
                    @Override
                    protected List<Triangle> doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        Triangulate dt = new Triangulate(drawingPanel.pointsList());
                        dt.preTriangulate(); //Set-up a bounding triangle and obtain a random permutation of the points
                        List<PlanarPoint> pointsList = dt.pointsList();
                        for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
                            PlanarPoint sample = pointsList.get(i);
                            dt.triangulate(sample); 
                            List<Triangle> list = dt.trianglesList(); //Obtaining the list of triangles at every stage. Good Idea??
                            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                                publish(list.get(j));
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        dt.removeTriangles(dt.trianglesList()); // Remove all the triangles containing bounding-triangle vertices
                        return dt.trianglesList();
                    }

                    protected void process(List<Triangle> triangles) {
                        for (Triangle triangle : triangles) {
                            g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
                            PlanarPoint p1 = triangle.getVertex1();
                            PlanarPoint p2 = triangle.getVertex2();
                            PlanarPoint p3 = triangle.getVertex3();
                            g.drawLine((int) Math.ceil(p1.x), (int) Math.ceil(p1.y),
                                    (int) Math.ceil(p2.x), (int) Math.ceil(p2.y));
                            g.drawLine((int) Math.ceil(p2.x),(int) Math.ceil(p2.y),
                                    (int) Math.ceil(p3.x),(int) Math.ceil(p3.y));
                            g.drawLine((int) Math.ceil(p3.x),(int) Math.ceil(p3.y),
                                    (int) Math.ceil(p1.x),(int) Math.ceil(p1.y));
                        }
                    }
                };
                worker.execute();
            }
        });
```

Here is the Triangulate class which computes a Delanuay Triangulation of a set of points:

```
public class Triangulate {

    private List<PlanarPoint> pointsList;
    private List<Triangle> triangleList;
    private Triangle boundingTriangle;
    private List<Edge> edgeList;

    public Triangulate(List<PlanarPoint> pointsList) {
        this.pointsList = pointsList;
        this.triangleList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
        this.edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    public List<Triangle> trianglesList() {
        return triangleList;
    }

    public List<PlanarPoint> pointsList() {
        return pointsList;
    }

    public void preTriangulate() {
        boundingTriangle = getBoundingTriangle(pointsList);
        triangleList.add(boundingTriangle);
        randomPermutation(pointsList);
    }

    public void triangulate(PlanarPoint samplePoint) {
        // A procedure implementing the Bowyer - Watson algorithm
        // to calculate the DT of a set of points in a plane.
    }

    public void removeTriangles(List<Triangle> trianglesList) {
        // A procedure to remove all triangles from the list sharing
        // edges with the bounding-triangle
    }

    private Triangle getBoundingTriangle(List<PlanarPoint> pointsList) {
        //Obtains a bounding-triangle for a set of points
    }

    public void randomPermutation(List<PlanarPoint> pointsList) {
        //Obtains a random permutation of a set of points
    }
}
```

I have 3 other classes

1. PlanarPoint - sub-class of Point2D.Double which implements Comparable to provide a y-co-ordinate based sorting
2. Triangle - A class which determines a circum-circle and circum-radius for the triangle and determines whether a point lies inside the circumcircle of the triangle
3. Edge - A class which represents Edge as the one having 2 PlanarPoints as its end-points.
4. DrawingPanel - A class which acts as the surface on which points are added at click events and drawn on the screen.

   Now, here are a few concerns which I have

   1. Is there a better way to show the triangles and possibly circum-circles by iterating over a set of points and then calling a function of the Triangulate class to get the existing circum-circles and triangles
   2. Should all the drawing be restricted to the DrawingPanel class since in the code snippets above I am painting in the class which extends JApplet/JFrame and thus whenever the window is resized, the drawn triangles are lost? Is there a design pattern which I can follow?
   3. Is the usage of SwingWorker over spawning another thread justified over here except for the fact that the time to compute the DT of a set of points is a time-consuming task?

If I have missed any details, please let me know

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: *"repainting an applet"*  BTW - as an experienced applet developer, I'll offer a point & a tip.  The point is that I would never bother to test new functionality in an applet.  Applets are harder to put together to the point of being runnable, it is quicker during development to design the crux of an applet within a frame, then transfer that working UI into an applet at the last possible moment.  This is often achieved by developing a combined applet/application hybrid, which only takes a handful of lines of code.

Comment: Re hybrid, see this simpler [animation](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).

Comment: @AndrewThompson,thanks for the tip. I was having trouble in making the applet runnable.

Comment: @trashgod,thanks for the sample code,I am making the necessary changes to the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't use `getGraphics()` to get a Graphics object since the Graphics object obtained won't persist if any repaint is performed (something out of your control). Instead draw to a BufferedImage and have the JPanel or JComponent draw the BufferedImage in its paintComponent override, or add your image data to a Collection of some sort, and have the paintComponent override method iterate through the Collection using the information to draw your images.
- Don't draw directly in a top level window such as a JFrame or JApplet, but instead in a component that derives from JComponent, often either JComponent itself or JPanel.
- Read the Swing graphics tutorials as they will explain all of this and more.
- SwingWorker is fully justified since you want to create a thread that is background to a Swing application yet interacts with the Swing application -- the very situation that SwingWorkers were created for.

Comment: Any particular reason why getGraphics() should not be used?

Comment: @chaitanya: please see my answer because it is explained above.

Comment: I probably refreshed the page quickly before you had finished your answer, so it just showed me the first bullet point. Thanks for the info and sorry for the impatient comment.

Comment: @chaitanya: No problem. It's partly my fault for uploading an incomplete answer, and then editing it. You're welcome!